# How do I re-evolve my crabrawler after canceling its evolution?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

My crabrawler was evolving and I accidentally pressed B instead of spamming A. I tried battling to level it up and using rare candies, and it still haven't evolved.

Answer (score 2):

Crabrawler only evolves when leveling up at at Mount Lanakila according to the [Bulbapedia entry](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Crabrawler_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).